# Memory management in Python C extension

Tags: python, c, arrays, numpy

I'm writing a C extension for Python that is going to speed up some matrix operation that is not covered bu numpy or any other library.

The operation itself takes 3 numpy 4d arrays, and returns 2 4d arrays. Since it seems like numpy C-api only supports up to 3d arrays I'd like to ask what would be the best idea for allocating all those arrays. Should I allocate each array as one contiguous memory block? Should I do it as an array of pointers to 3d arrays? What's going to work best performance-wise?

Comment: Anything you pass back to python should be created by the appropriate functions like PyObject, or hopefully some api which is easier and more useful like boost python or Cython or whatever. Optionally, I have allocated memory in c++ and passed back some identifier which python uses to tell the c++ code when to free it, but that memory is a black box to python.

Comment: Well I have used numba, and it yielded some improvement. But that's not enough. I would like to profile this code in C and eliminate all the bottlenecks.